# AVR / C (C++) I created a class with a pointer on a char array and I have a segmentation fault sometimes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, char

This is my class Cipher.hpp:

```
#include <string.h>

class Cipher
{

private:
    mutable char* m_matrice;

public:
    /**
    * @brief Uniqement pour debug. A supprimer en prod
    * 
    */
    mutable int m_xor = 0;

    /**
    * @brief Construct a new Cipher object
    * @param matrice Chaine de char entre 33'!' et 126'~'
    */
    Cipher(char *matrice);

    /**
     * @brief 
     * 
     * @param matrice Chaine de char entre 33'!' et 126'~'
     */
    void setMatrix(char *matrice);

    /**
     * @brief 
     * 
     */
    char *getMatrix();

    /**
    * @brief 
    * @param message tableau de char entre 32' ' et 126'~' 
    */
    void Encode(char *message) const;

    /**
    * @brief 
    * @param message tableau de char entre 32' ' et 126'~' 
    */
    void Decode(char *message) const;
};
```

This is the code of my class : Cipher.cpp

```
#include "Cipher.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/**
 * @brief Construct a new Cipher:: Cipher object
 * @param matrice Clé de chiffrage
 */
Cipher::Cipher(char *matrice)
{
    strcpy(m_matrice, matrice);   //Sometimes Triggers "Segmentation fault"
    m_xor = 0;
}

char *Cipher::getMatrix()
{
    return m_matrice;
}

/**
 * @brief définit la Clé de chiffrage
 * 
 * @param matrice Clé de chiffrage
 */
void Cipher::setMatrix(char *matrice)
{
    strcpy(m_matrice, matrice);
    m_xor = 0;
}
```

This is a part of the main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    char matrix[] = "0123456789";

// Constructor
    Cipher m_Cipher(matrix);

    int  Total = 0;
    cout << " Total égal : ";

// This cout // sometimes triggers a "segmentation fault"
    cout << Total;

// ...
}
```

This program works well, but throw segmentation faults depending on the length of `char matrix[]`:

```
char matrix[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX"; // Works well

char matrix[] = "123456789"; // triggers a "segmentation fault"

cout << Total;  // sometimes triggers a "segmentation fault"
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the pointer to the char[] but I need a dynamic char array and I don't know of any other ways to do this.

Could you help me to fix this please?
Note : This program is for an atmel AVR, then I must use the avr string library (https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html), not the C++ standard  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/string?view=msvc-170)

Comment: *"This program works well "* - No, it doesn't. `strcpy(m_matrice, matrice);` - the member `m_matrice` is indeterminate. targetting it for the copy invokes *undefined behavior*. Whether it "works" or not is irrelevant at that point. Use a container like `std::vector<char>` or (apparently) `std::string`, assuming the tag on this question is lying and this is really a C++ question (it absolutely is *not* C).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use m_matrice=matrice; That don't work. So what do you purpose to update the char array.

Comment: I use an attiny 84, so it's C and the standard string don't work proprely on it.

Comment: `cout << " Total égal : ";` That is *not* C. Regardless, you need to allocate space for that thing if you want a copy. `new`, `malloc`, however you want to do it.

Comment: I remove cout on the attiny. I use it on my computer only for tests. I will try the m_matrice = new char(strlen(matrice + 1)); but I'm pretty sure it will not work. I think malloc is the best answer indeed.

Comment: By the way the right code is : new char(strlen(matrice)+1);

Answer (score 1):

your problem is this

```
 mutable char* m_matrice;
```

with this

```
Cipher::Cipher(char *matrice)
{
    strcpy(m_matrice, matrice);   //Sometimes Triggers "Segmentation fault"
    m_xor = 0;
}
```

that pointer m_matrice points nowhere, or to some random location.

do

```
   Cipher::Cipher(char *matrice)
   {
     m_matrice = new char(strlen(matrice + 1));
    strcpy(m_matrice, matrice);   //Sometimes Triggers "Segmentation fault"
    m_xor = 0;
}
```

you need to `delete [] m_matrice` in your destructor

Comment: Thanks. It works on my computer. I will try it on the attiny later.